# How to remove old version of python in VScode from mac?

Tags: python, homebrew

Currently, I have all of these python versions in my vs code. I want to remove all older versions.[image: These are the all installed python versions available in my mac]

Comment: It's best not to touch the python that comes along with macOS for compatibility.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: How to uninstall them is going to depend on how you installed them in the first place. For instance homebrew will has its own way to do uninstall as compared to pyenv. You will need to read the documentation for mechanism you used to install to find all of this out.